# Why isn't media query working on my blog?

Tags: css, media-queries, blogs, blogger

This is my blog: [Blog](http://vkcreativework.blogspot.com)
I've written following code in its CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
.title a{
color: red !important;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
header{
display: none !important;
}
}
```

But it does nothing when I open this blog in any phone. The site opens AS IT IS whether you open in phone or desktop browser. Why is it so?

Comment: I can't find that CSS anywhere on your blog page.

Comment: Please decrease your browser width (less than 500px) and you'll see :) But it's not working :(

Comment: It's not working in phones*.

Comment: Media Queries demands a pay rise to work on your blog. She's on strike and hanging out with `iframe` round the back....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this in your header,
`<meta content="width=1100" name="viewport">`

Please change that to:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

For understanding how meta viewport works see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

What happens in your code is you have set "atleast 1100px" width for your web pages.

By changing that to device width, your web pages will be as wide as the device.

Comment: What does it mean? Could you please explain? Or there any link to read about that?

Comment: See details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Listen, I have changed the width to devicewidth, and it made a difference at least. But didn't solve my problem. I hope you can help me solve it. Now, my phone loads the desktop site again, but there are 2 divs (with class .separator in main content, where 6 images galleries are hyperlinked, please check home page) this time, that means the width of the content shrank a little. But why isn't it shrinking upto device width?

Comment: Thank you! The problem is solved. It typed something wrong.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.